# Cordova splash screen not hiding on android device but app is working fine in Chrome webview

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

When running my `Ionic 3` application on my Android (6.0.1) device, the app is stuck on `Cordova` splash screen, although **I can use it through Chrome WebView** (and it works just fine).

To make it even weirder the problem does not appear the first time I run the app after installing it, only after I close it and run it again (back button or swipe from task list).

Of course there is no error in the `Chrome WebView` console. I also tried to run:
 `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`
 in the console it does not work.

**Digging more**

What I realized also is that any preference I set in `config.xml` regarding the splash screen is ignored when the problem happens.
For example on first run:
 `<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />`
 does work properly, there is no spinner and the splash screen hides after some time. If I run:
 `navigator.splashscreen.show();`
 in the console the splash screen shows again, and `.hide()` does hide it.

On subsequent runs the spinner shows regardless of the preference. Also even weirder:
 `navigator.splashscreen.show();`
 does show the splash screen without spinner (on top of the existing one I guess), and `.hide()` goes back to the splash screen with spinner.

What I tried so far without success:

- `npm install -g cordova@latest`
- `npm install -g ionic@latest`
- Updated dependencies in package.json to latest versions
- Remove node_modules and platform folder & run `npm install` again
- Run `cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android`
- Delete package-lock.json and run `npm install` again
- Removed the splash screen plugin completely from my code, `Cordova` and `package.json` (and removed node_modules & platform folders), but the splash screen of death still shows!

Here is my environment:

```
cli packages:
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.2
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
System:
    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v7.2.0
    npm               : 5.5.1
    OS                : Windows 10
```

And my [package.json](https://pastebin.com/Fpph3wZm) and [config.xml](https://pastebin.com/xVc90a4z) if it helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using the corova plugin without the ionic-native wrapper for it?

Comment: I do use the Ionic native wrapper in my app.component.ts: `this.splashScreen.hide();`. I only used `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` in the console when trying to debug.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure. Do you wait for the `platform.ready()` event before accessing the plugin?

Comment: can you include your app.component.ts if that is where you are doing this?

Comment: Here is my app.component.ts
https://pastebin.com/mKSajB9M

Answer (score 1):

After starting from a new project, copying my `src/` folder, carefully installing  all plugins and testing the app I found out that the issue was caused by `Ionic Pro` plugin.

The following fixed it:
`ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic --save`

Comment: Removing Ionic Pro fixed my issue too! Thank you.